# Installed package Python not recognizing it

Tags: python, pip

I recently tried to create my own pip package. I followed [this](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) guide, uploaded to pip. And after I install it python just returns error that module is not found, even if I type pip freeze, the module is installed there.

Also I tried to install it on my Windows pc (prev. machine is Ubuntu) and it doest't work there as well. Any tips?

**EDIT:**

https://pypi.org/project/PyColours/

**The output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyColours'
```

Comment: yeah. share more info. like the output of your terminal and link to your pip package

Comment: Sorry MB, check out the edit

Comment: Your package is empty. Try adding some files before you package and upload

Comment: How do you mean empty? Only the description is empty as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You named main directory `PyColours_pkg` so you need to

```
import PyColours_pkg
```

Or rename the directory to `PyColours`, increase version, recreate and reupload the package.